# remap Caps_Lock to Esc and Control without X11

Tags: command-line, keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping

I want to remap my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to be <kbd>Esc</kbd> when pressed by itself, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when pressed with another key.  Here's the twist: I want to do it *without* X11.

I found [this answer from Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50176/57734) which says "write a simple udev rule" but I don't know how to do that.

On my other computer I was using [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) which is the functionality I want, but unfortunately xcape requires X11 (which I don't want).

I also found [this blog post](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/03/remap-caps-lock-key-for-virtual-console.html) which might be helpful but I'm too much of a newb to figure it out.

**EDIT:** [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83724/multi-function-capslock-without-x) over at Unix & Linux is basically identical but has no answer after 7 months.